# Variable in JS for-loop taking the max value

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have written a Javascript for-loop to auto-hide and show-on-click some content on my website, but for some reason, the variable is taking the highest value at the end of the loop...

So

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    $('.views-row-' + i + ' .faq_answer').hide();
    $('.views-row-' + i + ' .faq_more').click(function () {
        $('.views-row-' + i + ' .faq_answer').slideToggle();
    });
}
```

All `.views-row .faq_answer` elements hide as they should and all `.views-row .faq_more` have a clickhandler.
But for some reason the `slideToggle` line only applies on the line with class `views-row-6` (which isn't there)...

So the i-variable in the function doesn't apply on all values of the loop...
How can I make it apply on all `view-row-x`'s?

Comment: A search for JavaScript closures will help you better understand your issue.

Answer (score 3):

You should reference your element with $(this) in the click callback. Here, i will be equal to the last value of i.

```
    $('.views-row-'+ i + ' .faq_more').click(function(){
        $(this).slideToggle();
    });
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see, but you can get his parent or one of his siblings (I don't know the exact hierarchy) easyly with jQuery.

Comment: @Michiel Try my suggestion

Answer (score 1):

I think you are approaching the problem incorrectly. It isn't a good idea to bind lots of event handlers in a loop. You are much better off doing something like this:

```
$('.faq_answer').hide();

$('.faq_more').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().find('.faq_answer').slideToggle();
});
```

I'm assuming that your html is something like:

```
<div class="views-row-1">
    <a href="#" class="faq_more"></a>
    <div class="faq_answer"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript, variable has function-level scope. The interpreter will move every variable definition to the top of your function (hoisting) to make a reference to the variable available everywhere within such scope. Thus, inner function can access variable from outer function (closure). One gotcha here for everyone accustomed to block-level scope is that this mechanism includes binding loop counters to inner functions, which is an example of the case when inner functions has longer lifespan then outer ones.

In your case, therefore, when the callback get called, the selector will get a ***reference*** to your loop counter `i` with the value of `6`, i.e. it is bound to `i` not the value of `i` at binding time.

So you just need to pass the value of outer function's variable to the inner function instead of passing a reference:

```
$('.views-row-'+ i + ' .faq_more').click(
    // pass value of i into the handler, not i itself
    function(i){
         // return the result of invoking the handler 
         // so that we can apply the current value of i to this result
         // and bind the whole closure as a handler to the click event
         return function(e) {
             $('.views-row-'+ i + ' .faq_answer').slideToggle();
         } 
    }(i)
```

);

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the variable `i` it is probably best to find another way of matching elements

```
for ( var i = 1 ; i <= 5; i++ ) {

    // faq_more elements have id 'more' + i
    // faq_more elements contain class faq_more
    // faq_answer elements have id 'answer' + i
    // faq_answer elements contain class faq_answer

    $( ".faq_more" ).hide();

    $( ".faq_more" ).click( function(){

        var id = $( this ).attr( "id" ).replace( "more", "answer" );
        $( "#" + id ).slideToggle();

    });
}
```